# Creating a Node.js service for PostgreSQL: a json-patch runner

Tags: node.js, json, postgresql, json-patch

Having:

1. Some [json-patch](http://jsonpatch.com/) objects
2. A jsonb field in a PostgreSQL database

How to have a node.js code which take as input json-patch objects and which the output is SQL request that apply json-patches to database.
May I have to create this from scratch?

```
    [
      { "op": "replace", "path": "/baz", "value": "boo" },
      { "op": "add", "path": "/hello", "value": ["world"] },
      { "op": "remove", "path": "/foo" }
    ]
```

Example of operations to apply to a PostgreSQL jsonb field.

Comment: The site http://jsonpatch.com already lists some libraries (Javscript i.e). Are you asking if there is a Postgresql extension that already does this?   The current answer is: 1. Yes. 2. Yes

Comment: References I saw there are only for manipulating javascript json, not in postgreSQL jsonb. Can you share links you think about?

Comment: json and jsonb is the same format once fetched from the database. The question is: Do you want to to this in a Postgresql (plpgsql) function or extensions - or just fetch the data - process it, and write it back. For the later - there you can us one the libraries listed.

Comment: The service is in Javascript and would produce sql requests. The need is to translate json-patch requests into sql requests. No postgres functions and no data fetching.

Comment: You lost me, good luck!

Comment: Sorry. The question is: How coding a service which take as input json-patch objects and which the output is SQL request that apply json-patches to database.